# Approximation to colouring for bounded degree graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-optimization

I have already asked one question on colouring, this question is more specific.

Given a bounded degree graph $G$ with $\Delta(G)=2d$, is there a well know algorithm to achieve an approximation ratio which is better than a $d$-approximation for the colouring number $\chi(G)$?

Comment: What is $\chi(G)$? If the chromatic number, then the question doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Sorry is that clearer?

Comment: Not much - since $\chi(G)\le \Delta(G)+1$ and we can even test equality, moreover, we can also test whether $\chi(G)\le 2$, we can just output $2d$ unless we are in one of the special cases.

Comment: If chi(G) denotes the colouring number and not the chromatic number, you should change the notation -- maybe to col(G).